# Kafka Consumer Group implicit naming algorithm

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When group id is not explicitely set by the kafka client application, how exactly the name of the consumer group gets created, based on what? I see there are some cases when it incorporates the name of the server process (like when kafka-console-consumer.sh is used, then it is something like console-consumer-nnnn) that started the consumer, sometimes it reflects the fact that the consumer connected via listener without authentication (like anonymous.AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC...). Where is this naming alghorithm documented?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apache Kafka Documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

**group.id**

> A unique string that identifies the consumer group this consumer
>   belongs to. This property is required if the consumer uses either the
>   group management functionality by using subscribe(topic) or the
>   Kafka-based offset management strategy.

In general you have to add that property. But there are some situation, when you don't have to pass it, ex. `KafkaConsumer::assign(...)`.

Kafka Client (Kafka Consumer) be default doesn't generate `group.id`. Some third party libraries or program can do that: `kafka-console-consumer.sh` (`kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer`), spark structure streaming, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If group.id is not specified, the kafka-console-consumer.sh generates a random consumer group id.

For more clarification on this, you can look into ConsoleConsumer (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.scala) at [kafka](https://github.com/apache/kafka)

Block of code from ConsoleConsumer.scala

```
 groupIdsProvided.headOption match {
      case Some(group) =>
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, group)
      case None =>
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, s"console-consumer-${new Random().nextInt(100000)}")
        // By default, avoid unnecessary expansion of the coordinator cache since
        // the auto-generated group and its offsets is not intended to be used again
        if (!consumerProps.containsKey(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG))
          consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")
        groupIdPassed = false
    }
```